# Problems with putting the apply method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply

```
def mean1(x):
    return sum(x)/len(x)

df2['children'] = df2['children'].apply(mean1)
```

The error I am getting is the following:-
**'int' object is not iterable**

I think I am applying the Apply() function correctly. But still getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply `mean1` on the column, not the items:

```
df2['children'] = mean1(df2['children'])
```

Or better, use the pandas builtin `mean` method:

```
df2['children'] = df2['children'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

With a sample dataframe

```
In [372]: df
Out[372]: 
   0    1   2   3
1  0    1   2   3
2  4  100   6   7
3  8    9  10  11
In [373]: df[1]     # one column
Out[373]: 
1      1
2    100
3      9
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

and your function - modified to show what `x` it's getting:

```
In [375]: def mean1(x):
     ...:     print(x)
     ...:     return sum(x)/len(x)
     ...: 
In [376]: df[1].apply(mean1)
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-376-e12f9dfea5ae>", line 1, in <module>
    df[1].apply(mean1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4357, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1043, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1099, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2859, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<ipython-input-375-48efb527b53e>", line 3, in mean1
    return sum(x)/len(x)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

See `x` is `1`, a single number.  Python can't do the `sum` and `len` on `1`.  The error wasn't in the `apply`, but in your function, which was not written with single numbers in mind.

What were you intending it to do?  Take the mean of the whole column ?  Or the mean of an array or list in each cell?

```
In [378]: mean1(df[1])
1      1
2    100
3      9
Name: 1, dtype: int64
Out[378]: 36.666666666666664
```

`apply` and your function would work if the dataframe column contained lists or arrays

```
In [386]: df = pd.DataFrame([None,None,None],columns=['one'])
In [387]: df['one'] = [np.ones(5).tolist(),np.arange(4).tolist(),np.zeros(9).tol
     ...: ist()]
In [388]: df
Out[388]: 
                                             one
0                      [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1                                   [0, 1, 2, 3]
2  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
In [389]: df['one'].apply(mean1)
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Out[389]: 
0    1.0
1    1.5
2    0.0
Name: one, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, it was on point and clarified my intuition.